# Scatter plot for cube

Tags: matlab, plot

I am looking for a way to visualise a cube using a scatter plot.

for example it is possible to do for a cylinder thus:

```
[X,Y,Z]=cylinder(20) 
x=X(:)
y=Y(:)
z=Z(:)
scatter3(x,y,z)
```

I'm unable to find something similar for cubes.

I hope to then 'fill' this cube by:

```
x=[0.5X(:);X(:)]
```

and so on.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/235581

I've looked at the above, however none of them will work for me I think. I need to also have a colour value attached to each data point to be plotted.

Comment: Have you had a look at [`ndgrid`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the points inside the cube using `meshgrid` and then use `scatter3`,

```
figure
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(-1:.1:1); 
scatter3(X(:),Y(:),Z(:),3,'ob')
axis([-2 2 -2 2 -2 2])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, with a little bit of modification this also works for non-uniform boxes.

Comment: @Trippy, you are welcome, I'm glad it worked for you.